# Syncing contact groups between Google and Address Book

Tags: macos, sync, contacts, address-book, google-contacts

I just turned on Google syncing in my Snow Leopard (Mac OS X) Address Book, but I'm not seeing my Address Book groups in Gmail or Google Voice. Is this supposed to be the case? Is there a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sync (which is built into SL's address book only syncs the following:

-People's names and job titles

-Company names

-Email and postal addresses

-Phone numbers

-IM names, including the type of service

-Notes

-Photos (on Mac OS X 10.6 only)

([ref](http://www.google.com/support/contactsync/#anchor_link_3))

I'm seeing the same behavior in my google contacts too, it syncs everything but group membership.

Answer (score 0):

After configuring my address book to sync, it synced eventually, after being turned off for the night and being on the next morning for 3 hours.  I know the sync occurred sometime in the morning after turning it on, but don't know when.

I don't have an iPhone and couldn't get iSync to sync my contacts, or get the sync menu button to show up in Address book like it is supposed to.

After syncing, there was no record of the sync in iSync.

After syncing, I created a new contact, and updated notes on one of my contacts.  After saving and going into Google Contacts, the changes were not there.  I have that machine off right now, but expect those changes will be synced at some point after turning that machine back on.

Comment: My experience is unfortunately similar.  There doesn't seem to be any way to "force" address book to sync _right now_.  It just seems to happen at some point without any fanfare.