# Selective Google Contact Sync with Address Book

Tags: macos, sync, address-book, google-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syncing contact groups between Google and Address Book](https://superuser.com/questions/81476/syncing-contact-groups-between-google-and-address-book)

I'd like to be able to sync only one group in Address Book with my Google Contacts.  Any way I can do that?  I've seen that Spanning Sync supports google contact sync, but it's not clear whether or not they offer selective sync.  Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: This is also similar to this question http://superuser.com/questions/81476/syncing-contact-groups-between-google-and-address-book

Comment: Yes, it is similar, but part of my question asked about Spanning Sync, which was not covered under the previous question.  I do not think this question should have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you want to know about contact syncing is identified [here](http://www.google.com/support/contactsync/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=92997&rd=1#anchor_link_4).
I think the functionality you mentioned is indicated at point #4.

> **4. Address Book groups syncing**
>
> Currently, groups are not synced to Gmail. We're hoping to add this functionality in the future.